# Proper use of method overriding with multiple inheritance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, overriding, multiple-inheritance

Assume I have two classes like `Mp3Player`, and `DVDPlayer` and I am going to create a new class `MultiPlayer` which inherits from both former classes.

`Mp3Player` and `DVDPlayer` both have a method with same signature:

```
class MP3Player:

    def play(self, content):
        print(f'MP3 player is playing {content}')


class DVDPlayer:

    def play(self, content):
        print(f'DVD player is playing {content}')
```

I want to override the `play` method in `MultiPlayer` and I want to be able to call the appropriate super class, based on some conditions.

```
class MultiPlayer(MP3Player, DVDPlayer):

    def play(self, content):
        if mp3_condition:
            # some how call the play method in MP3Player
        elif dvd_condition:
            # some how call the play method in DVDPlayer
        else:
            print('the given content is not supported')
```

I cannot use `super().play(content)` as based on MRO rules it always resolves to `play` method in `MP3Player`.

What is the pythonic way of doing such thing?

Comment: I'm not sure it necessarily makes sense to use multiple inheritance in this case.  Maybe use a kind of wrapper pattern instead, where `MultiPlayer` has internal attributes which are instances of `MP3Player` and `DVDPlayer`.

Comment: Yeah, that's possible. But I am trying to understand multiple inheritance in python and I want to know if this scenario happens what's the proper way of handling it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use inheritance, you're saying that the subclass *is* a type of the parent class, just a more specialized one.  This is called an *is-a* relationship.

One common example uses animals to illustrate this. Imagine you have three classes: Animal, Cat, and Lion.  A lion *is* a cat, and a cat *is* an animal, so it makes sense to use inheritance in this context.

However your situation is different.  You have a MultiPlayer class, and by using inheritance, you're saying that it *is* an MP3 player, and it also *is* a DVD player.

This can work, however it's more natural in this case to use *composition* instead of *inheritance*.  Composition is a *has-a* relationship instead of *is-a*, meaning that your MultiPlayer class *has* an MP3 player inside of it, and it also *has* a DVD player inside of it, but it is not *fundamentally* either of those things.

Comment: Thanks John for your instructive answer. Are you inferring that such scenario may not happen if we use inheritance in its proper place?

Comment: Yes.  Inheritance is tricky to use properly, and mutliple inheritance much more so.

Answer (score 2):

I would call the `play` methods explicitly:

```
class MultiPlayer(MP3Player, DVDPlayer):

    def play(self, content):
        if mp3_condition:
            MP3Player.play(self, content)
        elif dvd_condition:
            DVDPlayer.play(self, content)
        else:
            print('the given content is not supported')
```

*Note.* — If you absolutely wanted to use `super()`, you could do that:

```
class MultiPlayer(MP3Player, DVDPlayer):

    def play(self, content):
        if mp3_condition:
            super().play(content)
        elif dvd_condition:
            super(MP3Player, self).play(content)
        else:
            print('the given content is not supported')
```

But I would avoid it as *it assumes there is no class with a `play` method between `MP3Player` and the common ancestor of `MP3Player` and `DVDPlayer`* (that is to say `object` here). If later you change your mind and introduce such a class, `super(MP3Player, self).play(content)` will call the `play` method of this class instead of the `DVDPlayer.play` method as you intended.  A class should never assume anything on the hierarchy of its base classes.

In addition, `super(MP3Player, self).play(content)` is harder to understand than `DVDPlayer.play(self, content)`, and it also requires an explicit class name. So you gain nothing but loose flexibility and clarity.

To better understand how `super()` works in Python, I highly recommend Raymond Hettinger's excellent article [*Python’s super() considered super!*](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)

Comment: Is it appropriate to access instance methods  thorough class names? I thought we use class names to access static methods and class attributes.

Comment: You need to pass the `content` argument when you call the `play` methods.

Comment: @Ehsan Yes it is perfectly appropriate to access bound methods through classes.

Comment: thanks @Maggyero for the side note, but `super(MP3Player, self).play(content)` won't work as the super class of `MP3Player` is `object` which does not have `play` method.

Comment: @Ehsan It will work because the parent class of `MP3Player` is `DVDPlayer` (not `object`) in `self.__mro__` if `self` is an instance of `MultiPlayer`.

Comment: @Maggyero, no in my example `MP3Player` is not inheriting from `DVDPlayer`.

Comment: @Ehsan It *is* for `MultiPlayer`, since its `__mro__` is: `(<class 'MultiPlayer'>, <class 'MP3Player'>, <class 'DVDPlayer'>, <class 'object'>)`. Try the code and you will see.

Comment: wow, yes you are right. I also avoid to use this as it can be very confusing!